# How to get a LSTM Layer in Tensorflow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow-lite

I trained a simple model with Keras:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20,
  time_major=False, unroll=False, input_shape=(28,28)), 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name='output')])
```

Then, I converted my model with TfLite:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("mnist_lstm_model")
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

I obtain a `UNIDIRECTIONNAL_SEQUENCE_LSTM` layer instead of `LSTM`. But I really need a `LSTM` layer for inference.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you understand what the problem is?